# How to understand the ops on Option as pattern matches?

Tags: scala

There used to be a helpful Scala Option cheatsheet on [this blog](http://blog.tmorris.net/), but it seems to have been taken down. Has anyone saved it?

Comment: Maybe express the question as: How to understand the ops on Option as pattern matches?  to avoid closure.

Comment: @som-snytt thank you for the suggestion, I had a hard time thinking of an appropriate title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get full version (with introduction) on archive.org.

[Link to archive version.](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206133026/http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Archive fu! What a useful skill.

Comment: @som-snytt: the question is "Has anyone saved it?". What can I do?

Comment: That was not sarcasm, I gave a +1! Sorry, it does sound deadpan. I even read the link and offered a diff comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note: [senia has provided the whole original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21123782/1714997), which includes the introduction and the cheatsheet (which is also below in this answer).

[This blog did!](https://coderwall.com/p/oobjhq) (I'm unaffiliated). The ever helpful cheatsheet:

---

flatMap:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.flatMap(foo(_))
option match {
  case None => None
    case Some(x) => foo(x)
}
```

flatten:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.flatten
option match {
  case None => None
    case Some(x) => x
}
```

map:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.map(foo(_))
option match {
  case None => None
    case Some(x) => Some(foo(x))
}
```

foreach:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.foreach(foo(_))
option match {
  case None => {}
  case Some(x) => foo(x)
}
```

isDefined:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.isDefined
option match {
  case None => false
    case Some(_) => true
}
```

isEmpty:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.isEmpty
option match {
  case None => true
    case Some(_) => false
}
```

forall:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.forall(foo(_))
option match {
  case None => true
    case Some(x) => foo(x)
}
```

exists:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.exists(foo(_))
option match {
  case None => false
    case Some(x) => foo(x)
}
```

orElse:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.OrElse(foo)
option match {
  case None => foo
    case Some(x) => Some(x)
}
```

getOrElse:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.getOrElse(foo)
option match {
  case None => foo
    case Some(x) => x
}
```

toList:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.toList
option match {
  case None => Nil
    case Some(x) => x :: Nil
}
```

coflatMap*:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.coflatMap(foo(_))
option match {
  case None => None
  case Some(_) => Some(foo(option))
}
```

duplicate*:

```
// This code is equivalent to:
// option.duplicate
option match {
  case None => None
  case Some(_) => Some(option)
}
```

*: Unfortunately coflatMap and duplicate is not part of the standard library. You will need to write it yourself or use Scalaz.

---

End of excerpt

Comment: The trick to remembering all of this without having to look it up is to think of an option as a specialized collection containing either zero or one elements.

Comment: I was going to say, You left off the last few you presumably didn't grok, but I must amend that to say that your source left them off.

Comment: @JCracknell How does that fit into the burrito metaphor?

Comment: @som-snytt I didn't notice it before. I've appended the forgotten `coflatMap` and `duplicate`.